# Drop-down list Empty option when data source is a macro

Tags: kentico

I'm using the following code as a macro to populate a drop-down list control. The problem I have is that empty option I add in my code is not rendered as an option in the drop-down list. I'm not sure why.

```
       private object ListOfRegions(EvaluationContext context)
    {
        var regions = CustomTableItemProvider.GetItems(CustomTableClassNames.CountryRegionMapping).WhereNotNull("CountryCode").Column("RegionName").Distinct().OrderByAscending("RegionName");
        var items = regions.ToList().Select(r => new ListItem(r.GetStringValue("RegionName", string.Empty))).ToList();
        items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" ", " "));
        return items;
    }
```

## UPDATE

I got this working by returning a delimited string instead

```
var regions = CustomTableItemProvider.GetItems(CustomTableClassNames.CountryRegionMapping).WhereNotNull("CountryCode").Column(columnName).Distinct().OrderByAscending(columnName);
var items = regions.ToList().Select(r => new ListItem(r.GetStringValue(columnName, string.Empty))).ToList();
items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select ...", string.Empty));
return items.Select(i => $"{i.Value};{i.Text}");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your new `ListItem` text, place something like "-- select one --".  Using an empty value and string, Kentico strips those out when generating the dropdown.  You should be able to get away with placing an invalid value too like "-1".

**UPDATE**
Based on your answers to questions, I'd suggest using a simple sql statement to accomplish what you're looking for vs. a custom macro method.

```
SELECT '' AS Value, '-- select one --' AS [Text]
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT ItemText AS Value, ItemText AS [Text]
FROM customtable_SampleTable
WHERE ItemText IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Modifying the line to
`items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- select one --", " "));`
results the option being rendered but with text in the option value as well as the text

Comment: Then place an invalid value in there as well.  The base setup of creating a list with values and text in the dropdown, checkbox list, radio button list, etc in Kentico says the value and text need to be seperated by a semi-colon ( ; ) on a single line.  If not, the single value will be used for both text and value.  So enter a value and display text.

Comment: I don't want an invalid value I want an empty value. I have read the docs and have also emitted a comma separated string. Nothing seems to give me an option with an empty value

Comment: Then use a simple SQL query vs. writing C# code for it.  You can accomplish this without an issue by using a UNION statement. `SELECT '' AS Value, '-- select one --' AS [Text]
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT ItemText AS Value, ItemText AS [Text]
FROM customtable_SampleTable
WHERE ItemText IS NOT NULL`

Comment: I appreciate your rapid responses but there is a good reason why I need this (and other examples) to be delivered via a macro.

Comment: Understood @RadarBug, then you'll have to enter an invalid value AND text in order for the macro to process it as you want.